# Qualified digital certificate for SSL

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate, digital-signature

Is it possible to use **Qualified digital certificate** used to Digital signature to client authentication during SSL? I tried to test if is it possible - run and configure Apache2 with SSL for server and client authentication. I also tried to use openssl s_server

```
openssl s_server -key server-key.pem -cert server-cert.pem -accept 44330 -www -verify 1
```

When I got my local server address, browser asked me to type token password but I got the response:

```
s_server -key server-key.pem -cert server-cert.pem -accept 44330 -www -verify 1
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Ciphers supported in s_server binary
TLSv1/SSLv3:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384TLSv1/SSLv3:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
TLSv1/SSLv3:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384 TLSv1/SSLv3:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384
TLSv1/SSLv3:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA TLSv1/SSLv3:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA
TLSv1/SSLv3:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256TLSv1/SSLv3:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
TLSv1/SSLv3:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256 TLSv1/SSLv3:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256
TLSv1/SSLv3:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA TLSv1/SSLv3:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA
TLSv1/SSLv3:AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1/SSLv3:AES256-SHA256
TLSv1/SSLv3:AES256-SHA TLSv1/SSLv3:CAMELLIA256-SHA
TLSv1/SSLv3:AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1/SSLv3:AES128-SHA256
TLSv1/SSLv3:AES128-SHA TLSv1/SSLv3:CAMELLIA128-SHA
TLSv1/SSLv3:DHE-DSS-AES256-GCM-SHA384TLSv1/SSLv3:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
TLSv1/SSLv3:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256 TLSv1/SSLv3:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA256
TLSv1/SSLv3:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA TLSv1/SSLv3:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA
TLSv1/SSLv3:DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA256-SHA TLSv1/SSLv3:DHE-DSS-CAMELLIA256-SHA
TLSv1/SSLv3:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256TLSv1/SSLv3:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
TLSv1/SSLv3:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256 TLSv1/SSLv3:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256
TLSv1/SSLv3:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA TLSv1/SSLv3:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA
TLSv1/SSLv3:DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA128-SHA TLSv1/SSLv3:DHE-DSS-CAMELLIA128-SHA
TLSv1/SSLv3:PSK-AES256-CBC-SHA TLSv1/SSLv3:PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA
TLSv1/SSLv3:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA TLSv1/SSLv3:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA
TLSv1/SSLv3:DES-CBC3-SHA TLSv1/SSLv3:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA
TLSv1/SSLv3:EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA TLSv1/SSLv3:PSK-3DES-EDE-CBC-SHA
---
Ciphers common between both SSL end points:
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA       ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA
DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA         AES128-SHA AES256-SHA
DES-CBC3-SHA
Signature Algorithms: ECDSA+SHA256:ECDSA+SHA384:ECDSA+SHA512:ECDSA+SHA1:0x04+0x08:0x05+0x08:0x06+0x08:RSA+SHA256:RSA+SHA384:RSA+SHA512:RSA+SHA1:DSA+SHA256:DSA+SHA384:DSA+SHA512:DSA+SHA1
Shared Signature Algorithms: ECDSA+SHA256:ECDSA+SHA384:ECDSA+SHA512:ECDSA+SHA1:RSA+SHA256:RSA+SHA384:RSA+SHA512:RSA+SHA1:DSA+SHA256:DSA+SHA384:DSA+SHA512:DSA+SHA1
Supported Elliptic Curves: 0x001D:P-256:P-384:P-521
Shared Elliptic curves: P-256:P-384:P-521
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
    Session-ID:
    Session-ID-ctx: 01000000
    Master-Key: 26E6219CED6C12DCF693AFEF900E1803CD05FB6C87B9B05AA04F7B8BFF075F7BA7BE871FA2A495A71160AB891CE9CF0A
    Key-Arg   : None
    Krb5 Principal: None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    Start Time: 1487932917
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
   0 items in the session cache
   0 client connects (SSL_connect())
   0 client renegotiates (SSL_connect())
   0 client connects that finished
   5 server accepts (SSL_accept())
   0 server renegotiates (SSL_accept())
   4 server accepts that finished
   2 session cache hits
   0 session cache misses
   0 session cache timeouts
   0 callback cache hits
   0 cache full overflows (128 allowed)
---
no client certificate available
```

Is it the final answer that is it impossible?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 0):

In general you can use any certificate with a key-usage that contains digital signature  for client authentication in SSL/TLS.

Usually it requires configuration of the accepted CAs in server side. For example, using Apache you can set [SSLVerifyClient](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslverifyclient) to `require` to force client present a valid certificate or `optional_no_ca` to set it as optional

OpenSSL `s_server` will work in the same way, you probably need to add the accepted CA so the client could select one.
certificate is requested.